# How to make a copy of object in angular which is sent across components?

Tags: angular, object

I have an array in object which I am sending to multiple components from main component.

```
<component-one [array]="Object.myArray">
<component-two [array]="Object.myArray">
```

And eventually I am modifying that array in a component. When I modify the array in one component, it is reflecting in other components too. That must be because the reference being passed to multiple components.

And my solution was to clone the array in component-one and component-two and then access the cloned objects. In component-one.ts and component-two.ts:

```
  @Input()
    array = [];
    clonedArray = [...array]
```

Now, I am manipulating the clonedArray. Even doing this is reflecting the array in other components. Is there any other solution for this problem or can some one tell if I am going some where wrong in my case.

Comment: you need deep clone, because the objects in the array still have references.

Comment: have you tried making a plain copy of the array and pass that to the components?

Comment: `@Input()
    array = [];
    clonedArray = [...array]` is not a valid syntax. Please provide a valid one

Comment: Have you used `Smart - Dump Component` pattern design in angular. Here, `Main Component` is your `Smart component` and `Child component` is `Dump Component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

child-component:

```
@Input("array") childArr: any[];

clonedArr = [];

ngOnInit() {
 // this.clonedArr = [...this.childArr]; // to clone simple array

  this.clonedArr = this.childArr.map(item => Object.assign({}, item)); // to clone array of objects
}
```

or, you can create copies and then pass it to the child component.

.html

```
<component-one [array]="copy1">
<component-two [array]="copy2">
```

.ts

```
copy1 = [...Object.myArray]
copy2 = [...Object.myArray]
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynu1rz?embed=1&file=src/app/component-one/component-one.component.ts)**

Comment: Ya, I can do that. But, component-one and component-two are rendering multiple times in a loop. So, copy1 and copy2 are being sent multiple times. Let's take in my scenario component-one is rendered five times and copy1 is sent five times. Even, if I modify copy1 in one place, it is reflecting in remaining four places.

Comment: Check the modified Demo

Comment: I checked your working demo and that's what exactly I was expecting. I tried it for array of objects and I went some where wrong. Can you check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjygyn?embed=1&file=src/app/component-one/component-one.component.ts

Comment: @MaruthiEranki To clone array of objects, try `this.clonedArr = this.childArr.map(item => Object.assign({}, item));` Check modified demo

Answer (score 0):

You've got confused with the usage of `Input`. It required a name which is in your case **array** and a variable to receive the input.

```
@Input('array') childArr : any[];

clonedArr = [...this.childArr];
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-llkt9e

Comment: I appreciate for your solution. But, I've found an issue with your solution. For example, in child-component.ts, try this.clonedArray[0]=5. Now, this will reflect in both the components. That was my problem. I want it to reflect only in the component it is changed and not other.

Comment: Yeah. That happen because you are updating the value inside child component. You have separate arrays for both children and you are changing the index 0 of both. If your array manipulation varies for each child, that won't cause a problem.

Comment: You can check with this `this.clonedArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] = 5;`. It will show that the arrays are not dependant.